# Use different array types in sorting algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

As part of one of my assignments, I have been given a set of 11 text files to demonstrate various search and sort functions on. The data in these files includes integers, floats and strings. I have used two sorting algorithms to sort the strings and integers and would like to re-use one of these to sort the floats. Would it be possible to adapt my code to use the float arrays as an alternative to the integer arrays?

Code for the algorithm:

```
public static void InsertionSort(int[] intArray){
    int temp, j;
    for (int i = 1; i< intArray.Length; i++){
        temp = intArray[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while(j >=0 && intArray[j] > temp){
            intArray[j+1] = intArray[j]
            j--;
        }
    intArray[j+1] = temp;
    }    
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++){
        Console.WriteLine(intArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: make it a [generic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it a generic method in order to parameterize by type. However, not all types are comparable in a uniform way, so you can restrict yourself to those that implement `IComparable<T>`:

```
    public static void InsertionSort<T>(T[] array)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        T temp;
        int j;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            temp = array[i];
            j = i - 1;

            while (j >= 0 && array[j].CompareTo(temp) > 0)
            {
                array[j + 1] = array[j];
                j--;
            }
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!